# How force "required" a select based just on another select

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with two selects and some other fields. I am using jqueryvalidation for this. My issue is I have the first select (countries) prefilled and required and only if the selected value here is "mx" then I have to make another select required (States).

The select is like this:

```
<select  id="pais" name="pais" data-placeholder="Escoje tu país de nacimiento" class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;">
<option value=""> </option>
<option value="mx" selected="selected">México</option>
<option value="af">Afganistán</option>
<option value="al">Albania</option>
...
</select>
```

The validation rule I have now is like:

```
pais: {required: true},
lugarnacimiento: {required: function (element) {return $("#pais").val() == "mx"; }},
```

This is not working. Any idea is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Regards,

EDIT: Adding more info

Here is the validate (full)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#fpp_form").validate({
rules: {
  esai: {required: true},
  genero: {required: true},
  nombre: {required: true},
  paterno: {required: true},
  fechnacimiento: {required: true},
  lugarnacimiento: {required: function (element) {return $("#pais").val() == "mx"; }},
  pais: {required: true},
  telefono: {required: true},
  email: {required: true, email: true}
}
});
});
```

Here is the second select (lugarnacimiento)

```
<label for="lugarnacimiento" class="required fixed">Estado</label>
<select  id="lugarnacimiento" name="lugarnacimiento" data-placeholder="Escoje tu estado de nacimiento..." class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;">
<option value="">Seleccione uno</option>
<option value="Aguascalientes">Aguascalientes</option>
<option value="Baja California">Baja California</option>
<option value="Baja California Sur">Baja California Sur</option>
...
<option value="Zacatecas">Zacatecas</option>
<option value="Otro">En otro país</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Show enough code to construct a working demo.  Where is the rest of your `.validate()` call?  Where is the HTML markup for  `lugarnacimiento`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the real issue is that the select statements are using another library:  `jquery-chosen` and that interfere with the validator.

My final rule (after removing the chosen library call) is:

```
lugarnacimiento: {required: $("#pais").val() === 'mx' },
```